# Automatic height, or, "filling / matching height" via CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure what the best approach is here but this is the issue:

Using responsive columns to generate two columns for my content. On the left div is a login pane, on the right div is a system announcements pane. By default, since no height is set, the div on the left is only as tall as however much content is int, and the div on the right is much taller because there's 5 system announcements.

What I want is for the login page to contain all of the info in one viewing area without scrolling down the page. For this what I would do is set the height value for the system announcements to some value, say `width:50vh` and then `overflow-y:auto`. This contains the announcements.

To have the two columns matching in height, I set `width:50vh` on `.col` class. However, I have some divs inside this column that basically spill outside of the div, it doesn't look good and overlaps other elements. I'd either like the height I guess to somehow be automatically set but to the height I want or for the content in the left div to properly "fill"? Not sure what the best approach is.

Code:

```
<div id="information">
   <div class="container" style="padding-top:0px;">
      <a href="http://linkremoved.com"><img src="http://linkremoved.com"></a>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="loginPageContainer">
   <loginUI:errorMessage />
   <div class="container">
      <div id="login" class="section group">
         <div class="col span_1_of_2">
            <div id="loginPic">
               <img src="https://linkremoved.com">
            </div>
            <div id="loginBox">
               <loginUI:loginForm />
               <div id="loginLinksContainer" class="loginlinkssection loginlinksgroup">
                  <div class="loginlinkscol loginlinksspan_1_of_2">
                     <a href='https://linkremoved.com'>Verify Your User Name</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="loginlinkscol loginlinksspan_1_of_2">
                     <a href='http://linkremoved.com'>Reset Your Password</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div id="helpfulText" class="helpfultextsection helpfultextgroup">
                  <div class="helpfultextcol helpfultextspan_1_of_2">
                     Your WebAdvisor username is also your Blackboard username. If you are unable to login, click the Password Reset link below to find the best solution for resetting your password.
                  </div>
                  <div class="helpfultextcol helpfultextspan_1_of_2">
                     * You will not see your course within your Course List in Blackboard until the official start date (review your class schedule).
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col span_1_of_2">
            <loginUI:systemAnnouncements maxItems="5" />
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#loginPic img{
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

#loginAnnouncements {    overflow-y: auto;
height: 50vh;
padding:0;}

#loginRedirectProviders {display: none;}

#loginHeader {display:none !important;}

#loginErrorMessage { margin-bottom: -7px !important; border-radius: 0px !important; }

.container { width: 67%; margin: 0 auto; background-color:transparent !important; }

#loginPane { float: left; /*Change this width as required or split this for each pane if need different widths */ }

#loginHeader ul li { margin: 7px 0 0 -4px; }

#loginHeader ul li a { padding: 2px 12px; height: 22px;}

#topLinks { background: #c10435; padding-top: 7px; height: 34px; text-align:center;}

#topLinks li { display:inline; list-style: none; padding-right: 20px; }

#topLinks li a {color: white; font-size: 16px; padding-top: 6px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 11px; font-family: "Titillium Web", Arial, sans-serif;}

#topLinks li a:hover {    transition-duration: 0.2s; transition-timing-function: ease; background-color: rgb(141,10,10); }

#information { background: white; height: 61px; padding-top:7px; padding-bottom:26px;
    /*background: url("http://edtech.com.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/edtechbanner3.png") no-repeat top left 284px;*/ }

#information li { display:inline; list-style: none; }

#information li a {color: white; font-size: 16px; font-family: "Titillium Web", Arial, sans-serif;}

#loginContainer .loginBody { }

#loginPageContainer {background: #eaeaea;display:table;width: 100%;text-align:center; min-height:58% !important;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom:21px;height: 569px;zoom:1 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 23px 6px rgba(239,170,35,0.75); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 23px 6px rgba(239,170,35,0.75); box-shadow: 0px 3px 23px 6px rgba(239,170,35,0.75);}

.login-page #copyright .logo {display:none !important;}

.newCopyright {display: block !important; text-align: center;}


#copyright { display: block; }

.login-page {background: white !important;}

.login-page #copyright {margin-top: 18px !important; bottom:0px !important; color:black !important; position: inherit !important; }

#loginBox #loginFormFields {margin-top:-5px;}

.loginBody { padding: 0 !important; background-position-y:33px !important; /*background: url("https://com-mig.blackboard.com/bbcswebdav/institution/Branding/Bb_learn_small.png") no-repeat scroll 94px 23px transparent !important;*/
    }

    body.login-page {}

    .receipt.good {
            margin: 0 auto 16px;
    padding: 12px 27px 14px 19px !important;
    width: 366px !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 720px !important;
    top: 652px !important;
    }

#loginBox ul {width:inherit !important;}
#loginAnnouncements ul {width:inherit !important;}

/* Target Firefox only */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  #seeClasses {
    padding-bottom:20px;
  } 
}

/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
    background:white;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }
/*  GRID OF TWO  */
.span_2_of_2 {
    width: 100%;
}
.span_1_of_2 {
    width: 49.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col { 
        margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span_2_of_2, .span_1_of_2 { width: 100%; }
}

#loginLinksContainer 
{text-align:center;}

#loginLinksContainer a {color:white !important;}

.loginlinkssection {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.loginlinkscol {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;       
    background-color: #c10435;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.loginlinkscol:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.loginlinksgroup:before,
.loginlinksgroup:after { content:""; display:table; }
.loginlinksgroup:after { clear:both;}
.loginlinksgroup { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }
/*  GRID OF TWO  */
.loginlinksspan_2_of_2 {
    width: 100%;
}
.loginlinksspan_1_of_2 {
    width: 49.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .loginlinkscol { 
        margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;

    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .loginlinksspan_2_of_2, .loginlinksspan_1_of_2 { width: 100%; }
}

/* #helpfulText columns */
/*  SECTIONS  */
.helpfultextsection {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
 .helpfultextcol {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
    background-color: #c10435;
    color: white;
}
 .helpfultextcol:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
 .helpfultextgroup:before,
 .helpfultextgroup:after { content:""; display:table; }
 .helpfultextgroup:after { clear:both;}
 .helpfultextgroup { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }
/*  GRID OF TWO  */
 .helpfultextspan_2_of_2 {
    width: 100%;
}
 .helpfultextspan_1_of_2 {
    width: 49.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .helpfultextcol { 
        margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
     .helpfultextspan_2_of_2, .helpfultextspan_1_of_2 { width: 100%; }
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure if this will solve your problem, but try changing `display: table` on `#loginPageContainer` to `display: flex`, adding `height: 100%` to `.container`, `.group` and `.col`, and adding `overflow-y: auto` to `.col`.

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox.

```
#helpfulText{
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
```

And height would left and right elements will be same. [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/djefLu98/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I"m more looking for the height of the left and right columns to match at all times, and then for the content in them to fill the heights of them. Your solution makes the helpful text div fit inside the space, but the left div column (.col) is still shorter than the announcements. I want to make them both a bit taller and have them match without the helpful text spilling out.

Comment: If you add `#login { display: flex; }` does that solve your problem?